# karma unable to find test files

Tags: angularjs, gulp, karma-jasmine, babeljs, browserify

I am using karma, browserify and babelify to run unit tests for angular 2.
Whenever I run it it fails with a 404 error like this

```
25 05 2017 11:35:22.974:WARN [web-server]: 404: /C://Users//me//git//proj-ng//modules//pack\\src//test.service.spec.js
 Firefox 53.0.0 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/C:\\Users\\me\\git\\proj-ng\\modules\\pack\\src\\test.s
ervice.spec.js
        wrapFn@C:/Users/me/git/proj-ng/modules/pack/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1055:30
        ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@C:/Users/me/git/proj-ng/modules/pack/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:17
        Zone.prototype.runTask@C:/Users/me/git/proj-ng/modules/pack/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:191:28
        ZoneTask/this.invoke@C:/Users/me/git/proj-ng/modules/pack/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:486:28

        Error loading http://localhost:9876/C:\\Users\\me\\git\\proj-ng\\modules\\pack\\src\\test.service.spec.js as "C:\\Users\\me\\git\\proj-ng\\modules\\pack\\src\\test.service.spec.js" from http://localhost:9876/src/test.service.spec.js
```

I have checked that the test files are located at the location it is complaining about. I have tried many variations and am out of ideas by now on what can be wrong.

Below is my karma.conf.js.

```
  (function () {
      "use strict";

  module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
      basePath: "",

  frameworks: ["browserify","jasmine"],
  browsers: ["Firefox"],
  reporters: ["mocha", "coverage"],

  // Source files that you wanna generate coverage for.
  preprocessors: {"src/**/!(*spec).js": ["coverage", "sourcemap"], "src/**/*.js": ["browserify"]},
     // "src/**/!(*spec).js": ["browserify"]},

  browserify: {
          debug: true,
          transform: [ "babelify" ]
      },

  coverageReporter: {
    dir: "code-coverage/",
    reporters: [
      {type: "text-summary"},
      {type: "json"},
      {type: "html"}
    ]
  },

  files: [
    "node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js",
    "node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js",
    "node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js",
    "node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js",
    "node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js",
    "node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js",
    "node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js",
    "node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js",
    "node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js",
    "node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js",
    "node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js",
    {pattern: "node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js", included: false, watched: false},
    {pattern: "node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js.map", included: false, watched: false},
    {pattern: "node_modules/angular-2-local-storage/**/*.js", included: false, watched: false},
    {pattern: "karma-test-shim.js", included: true, watched: true},
    {pattern: "node_modules/@angular/**/*.js", included: false, watched: true},
    {pattern: "node_modules/@angular/**/*.js.map", included: false, watched: true},
    {pattern: "src/**/*.js", included: false, watched: true},
    // paths to support debugging with source maps in dev tools
    {pattern: "src/**/*.ts", included: false, watched: false},
    {pattern: "src/**/*.js.map", included: false, watched: false}
  ],

  proxies: {
    // required for component assets fetched by Angular"s compiler
    "/src/": "/base/src/"
  },

  port: 9876,
  colors: true,
  logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
  autoWatch: false,
  singleRun: true
});


 };


     }());
```

my gulp test task is simply

```
const Server = require("karma").Server;
 gulp.task("test", () => {
    new Server({
      configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js'
    }).start();
  });
```